# SQL join or subquery help on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a dilemma that can most likely be solved by someone who is smarter than me with SQL.

I have 1 table that consists of eCommerce orders.  The table contain quite a bit of data but the most important is listed below:

Table Name: ORDERS 
Column 1: Customer Name 
Column 2: Order Date 
Column 3: Line Item

What Im looking to do is figure out if a client place an order after their initial purchase ONLY if they purchased a specific item.

Im looking for the SQL results to show me the following: 
**Customer Name** 
**Order Date 1** (First order) 
**Order Date 2** (Second order) 
**Line Item 1** (First purchase if it = "Widget 1") 
**Line Item 2** (Second purchase on second order date)

In the past, how Ive done is to loop through the first set of data in .php and query every row looking for the existence of Order Date 2 > Order Date 1.  I just think that there may be an easier way to do this using a JOIN or subquery.

Thanks much!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: It is not quite clear what exactly you are looking for. Must a client's very first order contain "Widget 1"? And you want to show the "Widget 1" order plus the one immediately following? Or any later order, which doesn't matter? Or the last order? Or are you looking for clients who placed exactly two orders, no less and no more? You see there is a lot you should clarify. Then: Where are you stuck? I'm sure you can at least solve part of this in SQL. To find orders with "Widget 1"? Shouldn't be a problem, I guess. So how far did you make it with the query, where have you got stuck?

Comment: The answer below was perfect at getting me to where I need to be.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the specic item is in the item column
you could use a inner join on the same table

```
select a.`Customer Name` , a.`Order Date`, b.`Order Date`,  a.`Line Item`,  b.`Line Item`
from ORDERS a 
INNER JOIN ORDERS b ON a.`Customer Name` = b.`Customer Name` 
    AND a.`item` = b.`item`
    AND , a.`Order Date` > b.`Order Date`
```